# Как создать директорию?

Tags: php

```
?php 
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
   $_POST = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST); 
if($_POST['domain']){ 
   $fh = fopen("domain.txt", "w"); 
   fwrite($fh, $_POST['content']); 
   fclose($fh); 
} 
if($_POST['content2']){ 
   $fh = fopen("file2.txt", "w"); 
   fwrite($fh, $_POST['content2']); 
   fclose($fh); 
} 
?>
```

```html
<form method=post> 
 <textarea name=domain cols="100" rows="10" id="domain"><?php echo file_get_contents("domain.txt"); ?></textarea> 
 <textarea name=content2 cols="100" rows="10" id="content2"><?php echo file_get_contents("file2.txt"); ?></textarea> 
 <input type=submit value="Сохранить"> 
</form>
```

Допустим в domain.txt сохранили такое (my.domain.cccc)

как сделать, чтобы при нажатии сохранить создалась директория с правами 777 (если нет, если есть, то все туда сохранить) с названием **my.domain.cccc**

**Или лучше сделать так, чтобы перед сохранением нужно указать имя директории (если нет, то нужно сделать)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkdir('/path/to/folder', 0777, true);
```

или

```
$handler = fopen("/path/to/file", "w+");
```

Comment: А на моем примере можно? Просто я так и не понял как это реализовать?

Comment: Можно документацию почитать – http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.filesystem.php

Comment: Если директории не существует, то создать как я написал в первой строке (рекурсивно создает директории)
Потом открываем файл и с правами на чтение и запись + если его нет, создается

Comment: не получается...

Comment: Звучит отлично. Может конкретики добавить? Ошибки?